# What qualifies for "mass disseminated data" for an abbreviated briefing?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-planning, preflight, aim

I'm reading about the different types of pre-flight briefings you can get and in the section for Abbreviated Briefing (AIM 7-1-4c) is mentions the phrase "mass disseminated data".

> Request an Abbreviated Briefing when you need information to supplement mass disseminated data...

Is there a particular definition or list of what qualifies for "mass disseminated data"? I often use [aviationweather.gov](https://aviationweather.gov/) to get a good overview of what's going on before a flight. Does that qualify?

Answer (score 1):

If you look a page or two earlier [in the AIM in section 7-1-5(b)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf) the FAA gives two examples:

> **b. Standard Briefing.** You should request a Standard Briefing any time you are planning a flight and you have not received a previous
>   briefing or have not received preliminary information through mass
>   dissemination media; for example, TIBS, TWEB (Alaska only), etc.

That's interesting because [TIBS was just discontinued](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/systemops/fs/faq/) (yesterday!) and TWEB is only in Alaska  (weather.gov says it's [in other states too](https://www.weather.gov/epz/pilots_guide) but that appears to be out of date according to [the FAA's procedures](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/7210.3AA_FAC_w_chg_1_and_2.pdf)). I have no idea what they include in "etc."

Personally, until I looked into this question I always assumed that "mass disseminated media" meant your local TV station's weather reports :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a particular list.

I would consider sources like the AVIATION WEATHER CENTER which you linked to, skyvector.com, foreflight.com, 1800wxbrief.com, even intellicast.com, all to be mass disseminated data.  I look at all those too, and then just ask for an Abbreviated briefing when I'm making a short local hop between airports I'm familiar with to make sure I get any TFRs and NOTAMs that may have popped up recently.